# How can i print a table which its first row is given by user and other rows are a multiplication of first row?

Tags: c

I wanted to print a table using arrays which the user inputs the elements of the first row and the elements of other rows are the elements of the previous row multiplied by 2, for example:
The user inputs 1 2 3
and the next rows are 2 4 6 and 4 8 12 in a 3*3 table.
I would appreciate it if anyone could help.
Thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   int a[100][100];
   int row , column , i , j;

    puts(" Enter the number of rows and columns: ");
    scanf("%d%d" , &row , &column);

        puts("Now enter the elements of first row:");
        for ( j = 0 ; j < column ; j++)
        {
            printf("a[0][%d]: " , j);
            scanf("%d" , &a[0][j]);
        }

        printf("\n\n");

        puts("The array elements are as shown below: ");

            for ( j = 0 ; j < column ; j++)
                printf("%2d" , a[0][j]);

                puts("");

            for ( i = 1 ; i < row ; i++)
            {
                for ( j = 1 ; j < column+1 ; j++)
                {
                    printf("%2d" , a[i-1][j-1]*2 );
                }
                puts("");
            }
}
```

I managed to do it this way, is this a good approach?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
   int a[100][100];
   int row , column , i , j;

    puts(" Enter the number of rows and columns: ");
    scanf("%d%d" , &row , &column);

        puts("Now enter the elements of first row:");
        for ( j = 0 ; j < column ; j++)
        {
            printf("a[0][%d]: " , j);
            scanf("%d" , &a[0][j]);
        }

            for ( i = 0 ; i < row ; i++)
            {
                for ( j = 0 ; j < column ; j++)

                {
                    if ( i == 0)
                        printf("%3d" , a[i][j]);
                    else
                    {
                    a[i][j] = 2 * a[i-1][j];
                    printf("%3d" , a[i][j]);
                    }
                }
                puts("");
            }
}
```

Comment: You should initialise the other rows, based on each previous row, **before** you try to print any of them. Also, why start the loops at `1` and not `0`? The condition `j < column+1` could lead to breaking array bounds too. It's best to write the code for computer indexing, not humans, which you are trying to adjust for by subtracting `1` from the array index values.

Comment: This is requirements and a code dump, not a problem statement. Both are necessary, but not sufficient

Comment: After edit: if your code works in all the ways you care about, SO is not the place to ask about it. Aesthetics are off topic. Try https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: So what are the topics I could discuss here? I am new to the website.